# How to deal with void-like functions in ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to have a very lean structure for a simple ES6 project. I'm obviously using Webpack to bundle everything, but I'm facing a roadblock.

In the JavaScript of yesteryear I was very keen on using `void`-like functions (changing something, not returning anything) and this worked pretty well for my jQuery-oriented DOM manipulation and canvas interaction programming.

Now delving into ES6, I can't seem to go on with this approach. Mainly because when importing modules, they have a very strict scope.

For instance, in my `index.js` file:

```
import * from THREE;
import update from 'my-module';

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
```

And then, in `my-module.js`

```
update = () => {
    camera.update();
}
```

I feel like it will be a completely different pattern mindset from here onwards, but having a hard time grappling which one would it be then…

Comment: `window.camera` is a global variable.

Comment: I don't see how preferring "`void`-like functions" has anything to do with using global variables.

Comment: Seems like a good time to learn how to avoid global variables. For example, you can pass `camera` to `update` instead. This makes your code easier to test as well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you're right. I rephrased the question to be more accurate. It's just about passing scope in without returning, with ES6 modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of trying to store** `camera` **in a global object, you should pass in** `camera` **into your** `update` **function.**

`<edit>`

Oh, and also, if you really want a global object to operate on, take  look at this:

- Node.js environment : Use `global.name = value;` and `global.name`
- Browser environment : Use `window.name = value;` and `window.name`
- Other environment : You can take any global method or property, such as `console`, and add something on to its object structure (everything in JS is an object!) while keeping the original value/function intact, like this: `console.camera = camera;` and `console.log('still works!');` and `console.camera`

For other global methods/properties, take a look here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects).

This is bad practice, though, so try to keep away from using these unless **absolutely necessary**

`</edit>`

**Best Practice:**

---

`index.js`

```
// Import external modules
import * from THREE;
import update from 'my-module';

// Define camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();

// Update camera
update(camera);
```

`my-module.js`

```
// Define update function
export function update (cameraObject) {
    cameraObject.update();
}
```

By passing in `camera` to the update function, and receiving it as `cameraObject` (Did this to avoid confusion with having two `camera`'s), you can operate on `cameraObject` as if it were `camera` inside the function. The `camera` object stays untouched after calling `update();`